# Atom debug react-native throw maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: react-native, atom-editor

i'm use Atom to debug my react-native project.
but when i 'React native : start debugging' at Atom, then 'Debug js Remotely' at iOS 10.1 Simulator, the app throw "maximum call stack size exceeded " exception.

then i use 'react-native log-ios' to catch log below:
*__nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 12 Connection has no connected handler*

if i use Chrome to debug the app, all fine.

any one can help me?
[exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVXz5.png)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/900) with [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io).